# How to pass data base query in URL of get request retrofit?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

I am creating a retrofit get request where i need to pass a data base query and some spacial character like '$' in URL in kotlin. But I am getting error.

**java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL query string  must not have replace block. For dynamic query parameters use @Query.**

This is URL which I am using in postman but cant in retrofil

**https://someURL.com?customParam=true&pageSize=100&query=$filter=(drivercell eq'1111111119')$orderby=creationTimedesc&withTotalPages=true**

This is the code of calling retrofit method

```
     val restServiceModel = DRestServiceModel.create()
     val model = restServiceModel.getTripsData("Basic bWs6SU9UMTIzNCM=", "application/json", "\$filter=(drivercell%20eq'1111111119')")
```

This is method

```
     @GET("inventory/managedObjects?customParam=true&pageSize=100&{query}\$orderby=creationTimedesc&withTotalPages=true")
     fun getTripsData(@Header("Authorization") token: String, @Header("Content-Type") contentType: String, @Query("query", encoded = true) query : String): Single<TripsResponseModel>
```

Please help me.

Comment: Show us the code, how you are building your query currently. Retrofit should be able to encode it for you

Comment: @MarošŠeleng I have added code.

Comment: thanks, please look at Dmitri's answer below and try to update the code. As I said, Retrofit should encode forbidden characters automatically, so it should work

Answer (score 1):

Problem is you are trying to put Path param in a middle of a query while supplying it via another Query. You should rework your request. Try something like:

```
@GET("inventory/managedObjects")
fun getTripsData(@Header("Authorization") token: String,
                 @Header("Content-Type") contentType: String,
                 @Query("customParam") customParam: Boolean?,
                 @Query("pageSize") pageSize: Int?,
                 @Query("query", encoded = true) query: String,
                 @Query("withTotalPages") withTotalPages: Boolean?): Single<TripsResponseModel>
```

And use it like:

```
val model = restServiceModel.getTripsData("Basic bWs6SU9UMTIzNCM=", "application/json", true, 100, "your query_goes here", true)
```

This way should it work.